# Parse WHERE php

Tags: php, parse-platform

I using https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk.
I want to send notify 2 other devices. 
But it's only send notify for device token is **'abcdef'**. 
How to send notify 2 other devices?
Thanks all,

```
    $query = ParseInstallation::query();
    $query->equalTo('deviceToken', 'xxxxx');
    $query->equalTo('deviceToken', 'abcdef');

    $data = [
        'data'  => ['alert' => 'Hello, this is a test'],
        'where' => $query,
        ];
    ParsePush::send(
        $data
    );
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `parse.com` is the appropriate tag for questions regarding Parse backend services . This question is regarding sending Push notification using Parse.com services.

Comment: @TaiNguyen Have you considered using channels for this purpose? However I am not sure if PHP sdk allows subscribing to channels. Though it might because ` $query->equalTo('deviceToken', 'abcdef')` overwrites your queries criteria. Liam's answer looks promising.

Comment: Thanks all, I solved it

Comment: @TaiNguyen Then share your own solution and mark it as accepted answer. That will help other people facing the same problem. :) It is encouraged on SO to answer your own question

Answer (score 1):

I believe your dual equalTo queries are overwriting each other. From what I understand, equalTo matches a single value. You should be able to see this behavior by inspecting a vardump of your $query after each equalTo call.

You should instead use containedIn (http://parseplatform.github.io/parse-php-sdk/classes/Parse.ParseQuery.html#method_containedIn) and pass in an array of values that you'd like the query to match. E.g.,  $query->containedIn('deviceToken', ['abcdef', 'xxxxx']).

Note: I don't have a parse PHP project handy so the above code isn't tested, but the general logic should work.